# Is it safe to call jQuery's resize() function to execute my own resize handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am defining a resize handler that positions some elements on the screen, like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Position elements
}
```

I also want to execute this functionality when the page first loads, so I just add the following right after the above code:

```
$(window).resize();
```

This works just fine. However, I'm wondering if I may trigger any side effects, harmful or not, by calling this function - I really just want to execute my own resize handler. Of course, I could do the following to make sure that I execute only my handler:

```
var positionElements = function() {
    // Position elements
}
$(window).resize(positionElements);
positionElements();
```

However, I'm new to JavaScript and I want to keep my code as concise as possible - this adds some boiler plate code to the mix.

**Edit:** In fact, my code can be shortened even more by using chaining. Like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Position elements
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see how it should be harmful, anything that could be triggered by a resize that is actually destructive should be avoided in the first place. What you are doing by using calling `$(window).resize()` is the same as the user resizing the window.

TL;DR; Yes its safe.

Comment: I'm not only wondering if it does something harmful, but also if it it does something unnecessary. I'm trying to avoid unnecessary code, but it wouldn't be much better if I have jQuery execute unnecessary code instead, right?

Comment: When triggering using `$(window).resize()` You also call any other handlers bound to `resize`, both your proposed solutions work, I'm just saying there is nothing inherently wrong with triggering `resize`

Comment: That wouldn't even be bad. Since this is a reaaally simple web site and I'm in control of all the code, I know that there are no other handlers installed. But even if there were some, the code would best be executed on first load as well I think.